# How can I search Stack Overflow with strings containing punctuation?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, search

I would like to search this site (Stack Overflow) using strings containing punctuation.

Example: I want to search for the contents of the following line:

```
tools:layout="@layout/activity_item_detail"
```

I *don't* want to search for the words tools, layout activity item detail, but for *exactly* the line mentioned above.

Currently, for as far as I know, it is possible to enclose a search term into quotes, but my search expression contains quotes. I would call my kind of search a verbatim search. All other searches seem to split the entered search string into words, which is exactly what I don't want.

I was not successful in finding a solution in the FAQ.

Comment: Use [this search page](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=) which is actually a custom Google search.